# How to set position of RecyclerView's item in Listview's item

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a Listview which has many items and each item has two textview and recyclerview.In recyclerview i have a list of images which is scrolled horizontally but the problem is,when i get json of recyclerview then all item are showing in any item of listview.Suppose i have 4 items in recyclerview of 4 items of listview.Each item of listview has 1 image in recyclerview but its showing all in every item of list.

I want this type of items in listview.

```
     No:1                  Date:
     img1

     No:2                  Date:
     img2

     No:3                  Date:
     img3

     No:4                  Date:
     img4
```

I got this listview which i don't want.

```
     No:1                  Date:
     img1,img2,img3,img4

     No:2                  Date:
     img1,img2,img3,img4

     No:3                  Date:
     img1,img2,img3,img4

     No:4                  Date:
     img1,img2,img3,img4
```

This is my Listview Adapter

```
public class POAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private Context mContext;

private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
private List list = new ArrayList();
PO details;
public POAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
    mContext=context;

}

public void add(PO object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}


@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    details=(PO)this.getItem(position);
    if(details.getHideStatus()==1){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row = convertView;
    details= (PO) this.getItem(position);
    final DetailHolder detailHolder;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.polist_data_activity,parent,false);
        detailHolder = new DetailHolder();
        detailHolder.poNoTv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.po_no_tv);
        detailHolder.deliveryDtTv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.Delivery_date_tv);
        detailHolder.metersCompletedTv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.total_meters_tv);
        detailHolder.recyclerView=(RecyclerView)row.findViewById(R.id.image_list);
        detailHolder.commentsTv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.comment_tv);
        //detailHolder.totalMeters_tv= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.meter_completed_tv);
        row.setTag(detailHolder);
    }else{
         detailHolder = (DetailHolder)row.getTag();
    }


    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
            = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    detailHolder.recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    System.out.println("DESIGNLIST" +((POListActivity)mContext).getDesignList());
    adapter= new ImageAdapter(((POListActivity)mContext).getDesignList(),getContext());
    detailHolder.recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);




    //detailHolder.lstImages.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    detailHolder.poNoTv.setText(details.getPoNo());
    detailHolder.deliveryDtTv.setText(details.getDeliveryDt());
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
    try {
        //compMeters = (formatter.format(details.getMetersCompleted()));
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){}


    try {
       // totalMeters = (formatter.format(details.getTotalMeters()));
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){}
   // detailHolder.metersCompletedTv.setText(compMeters+" / "+totalMeters+" Meters");
 //   detailHolder.totalMeters_tv.setText(totalMeters);

    //row.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 == 0 ? ContextCompat.getColor(this.getContext(), R.color.fst_color) : ContextCompat.getColor(this.getContext(), R.color.scnd_color));

    return row;

}



static class DetailHolder {
    TextView poNoTv, deliveryDtTv, metersCompletedTv, commentsTv;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
}
}
```

This is adapter of recyclerview

```
public class ImageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private List<Design> horizontalDesignList;
Context context;

public ImageAdapter(List<Design> DesignList, Context context) {
    this.horizontalDesignList= DesignList;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ImageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View designsView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.po_image_data, parent, false);
    ViewHolder designsHolder = new ViewHolder(designsView);
    return designsHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ImageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
  //  holder.imageView.setImageResource(horizontalDesignList.get(position).getImgName());
    Picasso.with(context).load(horizontalDesignList.get(position).getBasePath()+horizontalDesignList.get(position).getImgName())
            .into(holder.imageView);
    int workStatus=horizontalDesignList.get(position).getWorkStatus();
    holder.imageView.setBorderWidth(4);
    if(workStatus==1){
        holder.imageView.setBorderColor(Color.GREEN);
    }else if(workStatus == 2){
        holder.imageView.setBorderColor(Color.YELLOW);
    }else if(workStatus==3){
        holder.imageView.setBorderColor(Color.RED);
    }else {
      //  Toast.makeText(context, "No Work Status", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    final Design current = (Design) horizontalDesignList.get(position);
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, PODesignDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("poDesignId",current.getPoDesignId());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    holder.textDesign.setText(horizontalDesignList.get(position).getDesignColor());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return horizontalDesignList.size();
}
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public CircleImageView imageView;
    public TextView textDesign;

    public ViewHolder(View v){

        super(v);

        imageView = (CircleImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
        textDesign= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.design_color_tv);
    }
}

}
```

Please explain me,help me and guide me.

Comment: At least show us your Adapter(s) code. It seems you're using the same for each inner-`RecyclerView`.

Comment: Now i updated sir @shkschneider

Comment: You said "Each item of listview has 1 image in recyclerview"; If the recycle view has only one image per listView item, then what is it for?

Comment: Each item of listview has list of image in recyclerview and if 4 items in listview then each item of listview has a recyclerview and recyclerview has list of images,but which list of images of recyclerview i want to show on first item of listview,not showing only that one for 1st item of list its showing all images which is 2nd 3rd 4th item of listview,all are showing in 1st 2nd as so on...i explained also with an example. @Rabee

Answer (score 2):

Use the example below to achieve what you want:

1) Demo2.class:---------------

```
public class Demo2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView lv;
private Adapter adapter;
private List<String> items;
private List<List<String>> items_inside;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo2);

    items = new ArrayList<>(); // one dimensional array

    // Example: index 0 --> A1
    //          index 1 --> A2
    //          ...

    items_inside = new ArrayList<>(); // 2 dimensional array

    // Example: index 0 --> {A1B1 , A1B2 , ...}
    //          index 1 --> {A2B1 , A2B2 , ...}
    //          ...

    // populate items and items_inside
    for(int i = 0 ; i< 4 ; i++){
        List<String> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add( i , "A" + (i+1));
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
            tmp.add(j , "A" + (i+1) + "B" + (j+1));
        }
        items_inside.add(i , tmp);
    }

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    adapter = new Adapter(getApplicationContext() , items , items_inside);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

2) Adapter.class:---------

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private List<String> items;
private List<List<String>> items_inside;

public Adapter(Context context , List<String> items  , List<List<String>> items_inside) {

    this.context = context;

    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    this.items = items;

    this.items_inside = items_inside;

}


public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    final TextView tv_list_item;
    final ListView lv_inner;

    if (convertView == null) {
        if (layoutInflater != null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
    }

    tv_list_item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_list_item);
    tv_list_item.setText(items.get(position));

    lv_inner = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv_inner);
    lv_inner.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            lv_inner.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }
    });
    InnerAdapter innerAdapter = new InnerAdapter(context , items_inside.get(position));
    lv_inner.setAdapter(innerAdapter);

    return view;
}
}
```

3) InnerAdapter.class:------

```
public class InnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private List<String> items_inside;

public InnerAdapter(Context context, List<String> items_inside) {

    this.context = context;

    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    this.items_inside = items_inside;

}


public int getCount() {
    return items_inside.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items_inside.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    final TextView tv_inner;

    if (convertView == null) {
        if (layoutInflater != null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items_inner, null);
        }
    }

    tv_inner = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_inner);
    tv_inner.setText(items_inside.get(position));

    return view;
}
}
```

4) demo2.xml:--------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="100"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

5) list_items.xml:-------------

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:layout_height="75dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_list_item"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:text="A" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Date:" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll"
    android:id="@+id/lv_inner">
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

6) list_items_inner.xml:--------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="AB"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/tv_inner"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

7) Output:---------

[image]